# What can cause a signal 11?

Tags: linux

What is the most likely causes of signal 11, also know as "segmentation fault"?

Comment: -1 Seems like an answer not a question...

Comment: If you want to make an info type post, it is better if you work on writing a good question.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/

Comment: Accepted my own answer. I do not remember what I was thinking back in 2009 when I asked a question and answered it few minutes later. Probably I did not knew the answer, and asked before googling it...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Signal 11 (SIGSEGV, also known as segmentation violation) means that the program accessed a memory location that was not assigned to it.

That's usually a bug in a program. So if you're writing your own program, that's the most likely cause.

It can also commonly occur with some hardware malfunctions.

Comment: This is such an informative answer, why would it get 4 negative votes? (the reason it's only -3 is because I just upvoted it).

Comment: Got an upvote from me. What is the reason really for these negative votes?!!

Comment: I usually see segmentation faults as the catch-all error in low-level languages. Tools like {Address|Leak}Sanitizer, as well as debuggers such as GDB, can help to demystify the error and point to a cause.

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to [segmentation fault on linux/unix](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/segmentation-fault-on-linux-unix.html)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers